# filter collection based on value of field

Tags: scala

I have this collection

```
class ConvEntry(designation: String, saeThick: Double, common: Boolean)
val convList = immutable.List(
      new ConvEntry("16 Gauge", 0.0598, true),
      new ConvEntry("1/16th Inch", 0.0625, true),
      new ConvEntry("15 Gauge", 0.0673, false),
      new ConvEntry("14 Gauge", 0.0747, false),
      new ConvEntry("13 Gauge", 0.0897, false),
      new ConvEntry("12 Gauge", 0.1046, true),
      new ConvEntry("11 Gauge", 0.1196, false),
      new ConvEntry("1/8th Inch", 0.1250, true),
      new ConvEntry("10 Gauge", 0.1345, false),
      new ConvEntry("0.160 Inch", 0.1600, false),
      new ConvEntry("8 Gauge", 0.1644, false),
      new ConvEntry("3/16th Inch", 0.1875, true),
      new ConvEntry("0.190 Inch", 0.1900, false),
      new ConvEntry("0.204 Inch", 0.2040, false),
      new ConvEntry("1/4 Inch", 0.2500, true),
      new ConvEntry("5/16th Inch", 0.3125, true),
      new ConvEntry("3/8th Inch", 0.3750, true),
      new ConvEntry("7/16th Inch", 0.4375, true),
      new ConvEntry("1/2 Inch", 0.5000, true),
      new ConvEntry("9/16th Inch", 0.5625, true),
      new ConvEntry("5/8th Inch", 0.6250, true),
      new ConvEntry("11/16th Inch", 0.6875, true),
      new ConvEntry("3/4th Inch", 0.7500, true),
      new ConvEntry("13/16th Inch", 0.8125, true),
      new ConvEntry("7/8 Inch", 0.8750, true),
      new ConvEntry("1 Inch", 1.0000, true),
      new ConvEntry("1 1/4 Inch", 1.2500, true),
      new ConvEntry("1 1/2 Inch", 1.5000, true),
      new ConvEntry("1 3/4 Inch", 1.7500, true),
      new ConvEntry("2 Inch", 2.0000, true),
      new ConvEntry("2 1/2 Inch", 2.5000, true)
)
```

What im trying to figure out how to do is filter the collection based on various values in the fields.  i need an algorithm based on the list of true values, a list of false values, and a i need to find the entry directly above and below a given number.

is this possible with collections or do i need to do the old fashioned brute force loop method.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. In the first case, wouldn't `partition` work? It would collect the `List` into two lists depending on a predicate. To find an entry above/below you can sort of `List` by the value and then do a binarySearch.

Comment: *"i need to find the entry directly above and below a given number"* -- Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 2):

For the collection of true or false values:

There is a filter function on `Collection[ConvEntry]` which takes a function from `ConvEntry` to `Boolean`, the output of the filter function will be a `Collection[ConvEntry]` containing those items for which your function returned true.

For example, for the true entries:

```
val filteredList = convList.filter(_.common)
```

and the false entries:

```
val filteredList = convList.filterNot(_.common)
```

For the element before and after an item, you could use `indexWhere` with a function that checks the value, then use index - 1 and index + 1 to get the previous and next items. That's assuming that by previous and next you mean according to the order the list is already in. Though using a binary search as suggested by Boris the Spider in the comments would be more performant.

Note that Using a `Vector` may be more appropriate if you're accessing items by index. See [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) for a description of the performance characteristics of the various collection types.

Comment: Please use round braces when you can :) It means when someone runs an auto-formatter it won't expand the block onto 3 lines.

Comment: Changed as requested, though Intellij IDEA at least handles formatting those lines correctly.

Comment: That's configurable, the default reformatting settings will expand to 3 lines because curly braces indicate a block of code, not a single line. Also you shouldn't have spaces after the method that's effectively mixing infix and dot notation, stick to one; http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

Answer (score 1):

Use partition, it's better than `filter` for this use case:

```
val (commonConvs, uncommonConvs) = convList.partition(_.common)
```

The following function is a little complicated at face value, but will mean you only need to traverse the list once (if you use `indexWhere` you'll need to traverse 3 times). So it's O(N)

```
val init = (Option.empty[ConvEntry], Option.empty[ConvEntry], 
  Option.empty[ConvEntry])

val (prevOpt, elemOpt, nextOpt) = convList.foldLeft(init) {
  case ((prevOpt, None, _), cur) if cur.designation == "blar blar" => 
    (prevOpt, Some(cur), None)
  case ((_, None, _), cur) => (Some(cur), None, None)
  case ((prevOpt, Some(elem), None), cur) => (prevOpt, Some(elem), Some(cur))
  case ((prevOpt, Some(elem), Some(next)), _) => (prevOpt, Some(elem), Some(next))
}
```

Note the 3 results are of type `Option[ConvEntry]` as it's not guaranteed any 3 of the values actually exist.

This has best case O(N) as it's using a `foldLeft`, but if you used a while loop you could get best case O(1). You could also use tail recursion, but while loops are usually a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Using a while loop would be definitely not be O(1), you still need to traverse the list up until the matching item, which requires one action per item in the list before your searched item. As to traversing the list 3 times for indexWhere, that would be why I suggested looking at a Vector which would allow random access in constant time, making indexWhere performance equal to the while loop and, on average, better than the solution using foldLeft.

Comment: @AngeloGenovese yes, of course using a while loop would not be O(1), I don't understand why you feel the need to say that?!  Secondly the disadvantage of changing the data structure is you will need an O(N) pass with best case O(N) to convert the data structure.  Therefore using a while loop is still the most efficient solution.  I also suspect the act of constructing a `Vector` from a `List` would be more expensive than a while loop even if the desired element was the last element.

Comment: Sorry about the O(1), I must have misread the answer the first time. You're assuming he isn't in control of the data structure that is being built in the first place, if he is constructing the collection and he doesn't have any specific reason to use a List, a Vector may serve him better. From the looks of the data, it appears to be a (sorted) collection of material types, that's unlikely to change and really doesn't gain anything from being built as a singly linked list.

Comment: @AngeloGenovese fair point, and your answer didn't actually say "convert to a list" it said "use a vector" I'll upvote then :)

Answer (score 0):

For the true and false values, you can use `partition`:

val (trueValues, falseValues) = convList.partition(_.common)

For the values near some value, you might want to convert your sequence into a TreeSet. Also, it's more handy to treat your class as case class.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet
case class ConvEntry(designation: String, saeThick: Double, common: Boolean)

val convList = List(
      ConvEntry("16 Gauge", 0.0598, true),
        // the rest of your list goes here ...
      ConvEntry("2 1/2 Inch", 2.5000, true)
)

val myOrdering = Ordering.fromLessThan[ConvEntry]{(x,y) => x.saeThick < y.saeThick}
val ts = TreeSet.empty(myOrdering) ++ convList

def beforeAndAfter(saeThick:Double, ts:TreeSet[ConvEntry]) = {
    (for (item<-ts.find(_.saeThick==saeThick)) yield {
      (ts.to(item).take(1) ++ ts.from(item).take(2)).toList
    }).getOrElse(List[ConvEntry]())
}

scala> beforeAndAfter(0.204, ts)
res12: List[ConvEntry]] = List(ConvEntry(16 Gauge,0.0598,true), ConvEntry(0.204 Inch,0.204,false), ConvEntry(1/4 Inch,0.25,true))

scala> beforeAndAfter(0.625, ts)
List[ConvEntry] = List(ConvEntry(16 Gauge,0.0598,true), ConvEntry(5/8th Inch,0.625,true), ConvEntry(11/16th Inch,0.6875,true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I took bits and pieces of everyone's suggestions.  Here's what I ended up with, Still writing unit tests to make sure it works correctly

```
trait Converter {

  val pointTwo = (ret: Double) => BigDecimal(ret).setScale(2, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
  val pointFour = (ret: Double) => BigDecimal(ret).setScale(4, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble

  val convList = immutable.List[ConvEntry](
    new ConvEntry("16 Gauge", 0.0598, true),
    new ConvEntry("1/16th Inch", 0.0625, true),
    new ConvEntry("15 Gauge", 0.0673, false),
    new ConvEntry("14 Gauge", 0.0747, false),
    new ConvEntry("13 Gauge", 0.0897, false),
    new ConvEntry("12 Gauge", 0.1046, true),
    new ConvEntry("11 Gauge", 0.1196, false),
    new ConvEntry("1/8th Inch", 0.1250, true),
    new ConvEntry("10 Gauge", 0.1345, false),
    new ConvEntry("0.160 Inch", 0.1600, false),
    new ConvEntry("8 Gauge", 0.1644, false),
    new ConvEntry("3/16th Inch", 0.1875, true),
    new ConvEntry("0.190 Inch", 0.1900, false),
    new ConvEntry("0.204 Inch", 0.2040, false),
    new ConvEntry("1/4 Inch", 0.2500, true),
    new ConvEntry("5/16th Inch", 0.3125, true),
    new ConvEntry("3/8th Inch", 0.3750, true),
    new ConvEntry("7/16th Inch", 0.4375, true),
    new ConvEntry("1/2 Inch", 0.5000, true),
    new ConvEntry("9/16th Inch", 0.5625, true),
    new ConvEntry("5/8th Inch", 0.6250, true),
    new ConvEntry("11/16th Inch", 0.6875, true),
    new ConvEntry("3/4th Inch", 0.7500, true),
    new ConvEntry("13/16th Inch", 0.8125, true),
    new ConvEntry("7/8 Inch", 0.8750, true),
    new ConvEntry("1 Inch", 1.0000, true),
    new ConvEntry("1 1/4 Inch", 1.2500, true),
    new ConvEntry("1 1/2 Inch", 1.5000, true),
    new ConvEntry("1 3/4 Inch", 1.7500, true),
    new ConvEntry("2 Inch", 2.0000, true),
    new ConvEntry("2 1/2 Inch", 2.5000, true)
  )

  def resolveDesignation(intake: Double, commonParam: Boolean, round: Rounder): ConvEntry = {
    val tpl = loopSearch(convList.filter {_.common == commonParam }, intake)
    matchRound(intake, tpl, round)
  }

  def matchRound(target: Double, x: (ConvEntry, ConvEntry), round: Rounder): ConvEntry = round match {
    case Rounder.Up => x._2
    case Rounder.Down => x._1
    case Rounder.Closest if (target - x._1.saeThick) < (x._2.saeThick - target ) =>  x._1
    case Rounder.Closest if (target - x._1.saeThick) >= (x._2.saeThick - target ) =>  x._2
  }

  def loopSearch(list: List[ConvEntry], target: Double): (ConvEntry, ConvEntry) = {
    var prev: ConvEntry = null

    list.foreach { x =>
      if (x.saeThick == target) return (null, x)
      else if (x.saeThick > target) return (prev, x)
      else prev = x
    }
    (null, null)
  }
}
```